# Is it possible to use Tweepy to gather a random sample of all Tweets on Twitter for a given time interval?

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm currently using Tweepy (academic access) to obtain Tweets over a given time interval.

I am using a general query, and I only want a 100,000 Tweets. The Twitter API gives back the most recent 100,000 Tweets for the given time interval. Instead, I want 100,000 random Tweets from the given time interval.

Here is what I have tried with my current code in order to get the 100,000 most recent Tweets. Is this possible? If so, how should the code be modified?

```
# Imports
import tweepy
import json
import csv



# Store bearer_token in variable
bearer_token = "Input Bearer Token Here"


client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)

# Replace with your own search query
query = ' "Air Pollution" "2.5" place_country:US'           

# Replace with time period of your choice
start_time = '2021-11-20T00:00:00Z'

# Replace with time period of your choice
end_time = '2022-11-20T00:00:00Z'

tweets = client.search_all_tweets(query=query, tweet_fields=['context_annotations', 'created_at', 'geo'], 
                                  
                                  place_fields = ['place_type','geo'], expansions='geo.place_id',
                                  start_time=start_time,
                                  end_time=end_time, max_results=100000)



# Prepare to write to csv file
f = open('tweetData.csv','w')
writer = csv.writer(f)

# Write to csv file
for tweet in tweets.data:
    print(tweet.text)
    print(tweet.created_at)
    writer.writerow(['0', tweet.id, tweet.created_at, tweet.text])

# Close csv file
f.close()
```

Comment: Random is actually much more expensive than ordered (!= sorted). You shouldn't expect that on any professional API except it is really needed.

Comment: I disagree. I'm attempting to gather Tweets that reflect the actual distribution of Tweet content. 

For example, if I wanted to find 100,000 Tweets that comment on the air quality over the past year, right now my code can only gather the most recent 100,000 Tweets. If there are more than 100,000 Tweets about the air quality over the past year, Tweets from dates which precede the most recent 100,000 will be truncated, and the data will be heartily skewed towards Tweets related to recent air quality.

Answer (score 0):

Measure the recent mean daily tweet rate,
so you have a conversion factor
to go back and forth between
num_tweets and interval_duration.

Exhaustively query some recent timeframe,
obtaining some tens of thousands of tweets.
This is ground truth,
it captures distributions of interest.
Verify it by re-querying part of the timeframe
and observing the identical tweets come back.

Decide on Q query interval starts, randomly chosen, spaced far enough apart so we have (mostly) non-overlapping intervals.
Decide on R result tweets per query.
This gives Q × R raw result tweets.
Your requirement is Q × R > 100,000 final filtered tweets.

Identify ground truth "threads", sets of interacting tweets.
A tweet interacts with a previous tweet
if it is any of

- from same author and "near" in time
- a reply
- a retweet, from any author
- repeats quoted text, from any author

For example, we might see an hourly pattern
from a weather station that reports 2.5 M
at 9:01, 10 M at 9:02, NOX at 9:03.
Or another station that reports on one
location, then another, then another.

Identify heavy hitters, authors who frequently
participate in threads.
Identify whether threads are usually extended
by single or multiple authors.
Make R small enough that thread length
within each query interval is "short".

---

Now do a production run,
obtaining Q × R raw tweets.
Within a given query interval,
identify each thread,
and discard all but one of its tweets.
Tweets that survive such filtering
are mostly independent of one another.

Common mode events, e.g. a sudden weather
event, may still induce coupling among
filtered tweets that are near in time.

---

If (threaded) heavy hitters author a
significant fraction of the tweets
of interest, you might want to break
your queries into two parts:

1. Ask for heavy authors within the query interval, retaining at most 1 tweet from each, and then
2. ask for all other authors within the query interval.

Combine them to obtain the desired number
of filtered tweets.
This optimization lets you make R a bit bigger.

---

In the ideal case, you would ask for just
the first tweet within each random
query interval, and send at least
100,000 API calls. That is, R would be 1.

The point of the threading and filtering
is to obtain similar results, with big
enough R that we can reduce the number
of calls.